# exoplayer2: pause video at start with ConcatenatingMediaSource

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

While playing videos from a `ConcatenatingMediaSource` playlist, I would like the player to pause automatically at the start of a new item eg. not automatically playing it.

Using the demo application, I modified `onPositionDiscontinuity` function to detect current item change:

```
int currentPosition = 0;
@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity(@Player.DiscontinuityReason int reason) {
    if (inErrorState) {
        // This will only occur if the user has performed a seek whilst in the error state. Update
        // the resume position so that if the user then retries, playback will resume from the
        // position to which they seeked.
        updateResumePosition();
    }
    if (player.getCurrentWindowIndex() != currentPosition) {
        currentPosition = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

While this code pauses the player, *it does not clear the surface view used by the player hence we are still seeing the last frame of the previous video*. I suppose this callback is invoked too soon, but that's the only callback I found which was always invoked on playlist item change (`onPlayerStateChanged` might not be invoked).

**How can I have the first frame of the newly current item displayed instead of the previous item last frame?**

My weak workaround is to delay invocation of 200ms with `Handler().postDelayed({ mPlayer?.playWhenReady = false }, 200)`.

Comment: I don't know a better event handler. When the above works you can maybe seek to the default position of the current window? player.seekTo(0, player.getCurrentWindowIndex()) ? However, I'm not sure at what point in time onPlayerDiscontinuity is called excactly. So this might cause some kind of rebuffering. Maybe wort a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is not supported yet](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3876):

> The problem with using the event listener is that there is no way to ensure the request to pause in your event listener
>   is handled while the first frame of the new playlist item is showing.
>
> If stopping at approximately the right frame is fine, your solution of
>   pausing the player on position discontinuity looks fine, but I think
>   there's no guarantee that the video renderer will have kept up with
>   the player position which is why you still see a frame from the
>   previous source at the point of pausing the player. For what it's
>   worth, in my testing the video renderer did advance to the first frame
>   of the next playlist item before the request to pause was handled.
>
> A couple of other suggestions:
>
> - You could try customizing your MediaSource to insert a position discontinuity at the start of each period. I think then you'd get
>     onRenderedFirstFrame at the start of each item. If you pause the
>     player there you can guarantee to pause the player at a frame in the
>     new playlist item.
> - To get this to work perfectly, in the sense that the first frame of the new playlist item is shown and the player pauses before any
>     other frame is shown, it will be necessary to coordinate showing a
>     frame and blocking further rendering (on the playback thread) with
>     pausing the player (on the thread your app is using to interact with
>     the payer). This will require a bit of code, but I think it is
>     probably possible roughly as follows: subclass MediaCodecVideoRenderer
>     and override onStreamChanged to get the time offset of the new
>     playlist item. Then override processOutputBuffer. In this method you
>     can detect when the first frame of the new stream has been rendered
>     (based on the time offset) and then prevent processing any output
>     frames until you've paused the player on your app's thread. After the
>     request to pause has been handled and the renderer is stopped
>     (onStopped) you can unblock processOutputBuffer.
>
> We could also look at supporting this directly in the player, but it
>   will likely be a low priority at least for the moment.